# Is there a way to do a Regression in Catboost for a Gamma distributed response variable?

Tags: poisson, catboost, gamma-distribution, tweedie

I'm working on an Insurance model and I'd like to run Severity and Frequency models using the Catboost gradient boosting algorithm. The problem is that according to the literature, a Severity model assumes a Gamma distributed response variable, while according to the Catboost documentation, a Gamma objective model is not supported. Is there a way utilize one of the existing objectives (e.g. Poisson or Tweedie), to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the `variance_power` (`p` symbol in the literature) parameter of Tweedie distribution to 2 to get a Gamma distribution.

example:

```
CatBoostRegressor(loss_function='Tweedie:variance_power=2', n_estimators=500, silent=True)
```

Comment: with "catboost==1.1.1" and python=3.7 on gnu-linux, i got this error:
`CatBoostError: catboost/libs/metrics/metric.cpp:1552: Tweedie metric is defined for 1 < variance_power < 2, got 2`

Comment: You must input a value between 1 and 2. The denominator blows up at 1 or 2. If you want to use 1, that is equivalent to Poisson loss. If you want to use 2, that is equivalent to a Gamma loss, which Catboost does not seem to support natively.